# PHP if i fill variable from post data is it always set?

Tags: php, isset

I have a simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer to it. 
i have a piece of code like this:

```
$app->put('/user/', function () use ($app) {

  $isValid      = true;
  $message      = null;
  $newuserID        = null;
  $session_token    = null;
  $jsonUserData     = $app->request->put('user');

  if(!isset($jsonUserData) ){
    $isValid = false;
    $message = 'er ging iets mis';
  }else{
    //handle rest of code.
  }
}
```

will `isset($jsonUserData)` always return true because i declare it with

```
$jsonUserdata = $app->request->put('user');
```

or will it return as false if 
`$app->request->put('user');` was empty

Slim api documents says that it handles its variables with

> If a variable does not exist, each method above will return null. You
>   can also invoke any of these functions without an argument to obtain
>   an array of all variables of the given type:

Comment: it depends on this method `$app->request->put`

Comment: please refer manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php - example tells that $var = ''; return true.

Comment: So the answer would be No it doesn't always return true. slim api's default's their parameters to return null when empty.

Answer (score 0):

See Documentation at php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Isset just checks if a variable exists, not its content. so if there is any line of code with

```
$XX = ...
isset($XX); // will return true.
```

You can use:

```
if(!isset($jsonUserData) || $jsonUserData == null){
  ...
}
```

Exception: you can destroy variables with unset($XX). Then isset will return false because this variable does no longer exists.

Comment: `bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )
Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.` so `|| json/userdata == null` is unnecessary